# Ip aliasing on cisco router

Tags: cisco, ip, networking

We have a D-Link router (DSL-2730R) with the **"Alias Ip Address"** feature. This enable a logical network from the primary IP.

[image]

**I want to do the same on the Router Cisco Rv-110w, ¿it's possible, what option do the same?**

Comment: Product and/or Ressource recommendations are off topic.

Comment: What does that feature do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, from this [Cisco RV110W administration guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv110w/administration/guide/rv110w_admin.pdf) it seems there's no option to configure a secondary IP address.

Comment: I already read the guide, but I thought there might be some option.

Comment: It is indeed difficult to prove a negative. All IOS-based devices should do it. In IOS the command would be "ip address x.x.x.x y.y.y.y secondary". Personally I tend to avoid non-IOS SMB Cisco devices.